# Como somar as tags <li>

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de saber como faço para somar a quantidade de `<li>`

Segue um exemplo:

```html
<ul>
    <li>exemplo 1</li>
     <li>exemplo 2</li>
     <li>exemplo 3</li>
     <li>exemplo 4</li>
  </ul>

<p class="mostrar_resultado"> 4 </p>
```

Answer (score 4):

Sem jQuery: [`document.querySelectorAll().length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) te dá a resposta

```html
<ul>
    <li>exemplo 1</li>
     <li>exemplo 2</li>
     <li>exemplo 3</li>
     <li>exemplo 4</li>
  </ul>

<p id="resultado" class="mostrar_resultado"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML =
    document.querySelectorAll('li').length;
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Com JQuery, utilize o `$("li").length`.

```js
$(".mostrar_resultado").text($("li").length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>exemplo 1</li>
  <li>exemplo 2</li>
  <li>exemplo 3</li>
  <li>exemplo 4</li>
</ul>

<p class="mostrar_resultado"></p>
```

Segue [documentação](https://api.jquery.com/length/) do `.length()`